# What is the generic type of HStack?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm building a calculator app in SwiftUI as part of an iOS development course. The UI is as follows:

[image]

As we can see, there five rows of buttons, each button has a text, as well as the result panel is a text. Thus, extracting the text, buttons and rows into separate views works perfectly. Following is the code that creates a row.

```
struct RowView: View {
    let buttons: [CalculatorButton]
    @Binding var result: String
    let calc: Calculator
    
    var body: some View {
        createCells(self.buttons)
    }
    
    private func createCells(_ buttons: [CalculatorButton]) -> some View {
        if buttons.count % 2 == 0 {
            return AnyView(HStack(spacing: 1) {
                ForEach(buttons, id: \.label) { button in
                    ButtonView(button: button, result: self.$result, calc: self.calc)
                }
            })
        } else {
            return AnyView(HStack(spacing: 1) {
                ButtonView(button: buttons[0], result: self.$result, calc: self.calc)
                createCells(buttons.suffix(2))
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is that if there are even number of buttons in a row, they are simply stacked horizontally. For the last row, we manually place the first button, and then make a recursive call that places the remaining two buttons horizontally. Sweet!

However, the `AnyView(HStack(spacing: 1)` code is repeated in the `if-else` block. I tried to create a local variable for the contents of the `HStack`, but couldn't find a type that successfully compiled for both `if` and `else`.
Is it possible to do so? I'm using Xcode 11.5, with Swift 5.

Comment: Ok, to avoid guessing, would you provide minimal compilable example w/o extra dependencies or with provided all needed dependencies?

Comment: @Asperi The project is on [GitHub](https://github.com/asarkar/ios-bootcamp/tree/master/Calculator-SwiftUI), it really has 3 files. The class in question is [ContentView](https://github.com/asarkar/ios-bootcamp/blob/master/Calculator-SwiftUI/Calculator-SwiftUI/View/ContentView.swift).